# Check the value of all variables inside an php file

Tags: php, arrays

index.php file:

```
<?php
 include 'phpinfoip.php';
 if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip))
 if (in_array('1', $ip, true))
?>
```

phpinfoip.php file:

```
<?php
 $ip = array('127.0.0.1', '1');
?>
```

I would like to check one value in all variables inside the file, without having to call them by name ($ip1, $ip2... etc) to apply the following logic:

if xxx variables has the array value = 1
Run the code

In other words, I would like to get something like:

```
<?php
 include 'phpinfoip.php';
 if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip))
 if (in_array('1', $allvariables, true))
?>
```

I think this question is crazy, and maybe impossible? sorry if it's a bother.
(complementary alternatives with javascript are acceptable)

Comment: Using numbered variables names is what is crazy to begin with … that’s what _arrays_ are for.

Comment: @misorude print_r($iptest); //Array ( [0] => 127.0.0.1 [1] => 1 )                          print_r($iptest); // Array ( [a] => 127.0.0.1 [b] => 1 )

Comment: Okay, and what exactly do you want to do with those values now? Still pretty much unclear.

Comment: This code is a complement to another script (timer)

The purpose is to create an anti-flood for certain tasks in my app. I will use the code to capture the ip, and then relate the ip with the value '1'. The value '1' is related, and is used as an example to represent the number of times that the ip made the request.

I store the information obtained in an external php to call on the main page.

Comment: Well then you should probably start by using the IP as an array _index_, and sum up the number of calls under that index.

Comment: Summary.. the idea is to mitigate post\get request attacks in my php script for a few seconds, after the user reaches 5 attempts, for example.

Comment: But I already _made_ the request, and your script is already _handling_ it … so this is going to consume resources on your server either way.

Comment: @misorude I'm still new to php, any example is welcome.

I looked in the php documentation, this is not clear, I don't found things that explain me correctly about (array_sum and similar methods)

Comment: Yes you are right, but the user will run a line of minor code.

Since the original line of code stores information. Avoiding the flood, we mitigate data attacks for a short time.

Comment: You would need to store the info which IP made how many requests somewhere, either by writing your updated array to a file, or keeping this info in the database. That operation alone is probably going to cost as much as the other “minor” operation you are performing, so there’s rather little point in this to begin with.

Comment: I can limit the number of IP connections and redirect the request to another script.

Well, my problem now is not this, I need to solve the main problem and only after that, I need to think about the next problems.

Comment: You should probably go with a database to begin with, because if you stored this data in an array, you would also need a mechanism to remove “old” entries from that array, otherwise it would grow to a size that your script won’t be able to handle any more at some point.